# SharePoint Search Bar

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, search

I've a SP2010 Site with numerous pages, so many so that the Global Navigation bar is split across 2 lines.

I'm wondering if it's possible to amend the Master Page to move the location of the Search Bar (which is found on the same line as the Global Navigation) in order that it may possibly allow all pages to be shown on a single line within the Global Navigation.

*N.B - I'm a novice when it comes to developing SharePoint & haven't really used SP Designer before, so if that is the solution, if anyone could explain the finite detail to me of how to apply the fix here it would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 1):

I can get you started by pointing you in the direction of some useful posts on the web:

Introduction to Master Pages SP2010 : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-sharepoint-master-pages-dc9c4388-8dce-41b8-abb8-eeda2801b1a7

Customise a master page to brand your site: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-a-master-page-to-brand-your-site-0a57b837-4c97-4af9-a088-fedf3dfd1dd5

And specifically what to look for with your search box > Find the [asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea"] tag. Move this where you would like it on the page.

Always make a copy and make your changes rather than modify the default master page - you may need to roll back one day if any of your new changes break your site :)

Hope this helps.